# CakePHP - How to dynamically change the fields in my form after selecting from drop-down list

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am having a trouble on getting the value of the selected drop-down list(package_id) to populate the next fields particularly the Departure Time and Price which is in the Package Model.

Here is my code in View/Reservations/package.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Reservation'); ?>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <?php
                echo $this->Html->tableCells(array(
                    array(
                        'Date: ',
                        $this->Form->input('date', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'datepicker'))
                        ),
                    array(
                        'Package Name:', 
                        $this->Form->input('package_id', array('label' => false, 'options' => $name, 'id' => 'PackageID', 'empty' => '-- Select Package --'))
                        ),
                    array(
                        'Departure Time:', 
                        $this->Form->input('departure_time', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'label', 'id' => 'test'))
                        ),
                    array(
                        'Price:', 
                        $this->Form->input('price', array('label' => false, 'id' => 'test'))
                        ),
                    array(
                        'Number of Person:', 
                        $this->Form->input('number_of_people', array('label' => false))
                        ),
                    array(
                        'Total Price:', 
                        $this->Form->input('price', array('label' => false))
                        ),
                    array(
                        '',
                        $this->Form->Submit('Book Now', array('class' => 'button'))
                        ),
                ));
            ?>
        </table>
```

and Here is my code in public function package():

```
$options = $this->Packages->find('list'); //or whatever conditions you want
$this->set('name', $options);
```

I was trying to use JS helper but I can't get it right here is my code:

```
$this->Js->get('#PackageID');
$this->Js->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'Reservation',
        'action'=>'getPackage'
        ), array(
        'update'=> '#test',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression' => true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true))
        )
    )
);
```

Feel free to ask questions for clarification. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Do print_r($name) in view, did you see any data?

Comment: @NTkhan hi. this data shows Array ( [1] => Coron Town Tour [2] => Coron Island Tour [5] => Island Escapade Tour [6] => Wrecks and Reefs Tour [7] => Culion Historical Tour [8] => Calauit Tour (By Land) [9] => Calauit Tour (By Sea) ) but it is not in the select field

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
in the view .ctp , add this js function :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $("#PackageID").chosen().bind('change', function() {
            $.post('/project_name/controller_name/listDeparetementByPackage/'+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#test").empty().append(data);
            $("#test").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }, 'html'); 

        });
     });   
</script>
```

and in your controller , here is the function to get the departements by pacakge id :

```
function listDeparetementByPackage($package = null ) {


    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->beforeRender();
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $data = $this->Package->Departement->find('list', array('fields' => array('Departement.id', 'Departement.libelle'), 
                                        'conditions' => array('Departement.package_id' => $package),     
                                        'recursive' => 0    ));
    if(count($data)>0){
        foreach($data as $key => $val) {
            echo "<option value=$key>$val</option>";
        }
    }else{
    echo "<option></option>"; // if the result is empty , show a select empty
    }

}
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: yep , you can do whatever you want , i just gived an example.

Comment: when i do echo  `$this->form->input($key);` there is no output, how should i do. plz if you know.

Comment: @MaungYeHtunZaw: This should help $this->form->input('outputData',['value' => $key]). Also see this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-input-elements)